# Prime factorization stacks

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to write a program that takes a number and then determines the prime numbers that you can multiply together to get the number entered. For example if you enter 3960 you should get 11 * 5 * 3 * 3 * 2 * 2 *2 However I can't get the answer to print. Is there something I'm missing in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Stack.h"
#include "Stack.cpp"

int main(void)
{
   Stack s;
   int num;
   string answer;


   cout << "Enter a number greater than one: ";
   cin >> num;

   for(int i=0; i <= num; i++){
    if((num%i) == 0){
        s.push(i);
    }
   }

    while(!s.empty()){
        answer = s.top();
        cout << answer;
        cout << "*";
        s.pop();
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never change `num`, and change `i` unconditionally

Comment: Once you fix the division by zero, your prime factorization of 8 will be 8 * 4 * 2 * 1. You need to 1) only test prime numbers; 2) take duplicated factors into account.

Comment: Has the factorization to be the smallest possible?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Prime factorizations are unique.

Comment: Do you really have a stack where you push `int`s and pop `string`s? (Note that you really *don't* want to assign an `int` to a `string`, even though it's not a compilation error. You don't even need `answer` - `cout << s.top();` will do.)

Comment: `#include "Stack.cpp"` that's not how this is ("normally") supposed to work ... you need to compile Stack.cpp separately and then link the resulting object files together.